# Xamarin Xam.Plugin.Media can't work out how to access camera

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to create a Xamarin app that can access the camera (I don't need to store any photos taken or anything, just need to be able to start the camera via a button click.) I am using an Android device to test the app on.

I installed the Xam.Plugin.Media plugin. I added the following to the application-tag in the AndroidManifest:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">

  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

I created a new folder in the Android project, under Resources called xml. I created a new file in the xml folder called file_paths.xml, and I put the following in that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

And finally I added this code to my MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
    public void CameraClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        testAsync();
    }

    async void testAsync() {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported) {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Camera available!", "OK");

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

        }
        else {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Camera unavailable!", ":(");
        }
    }
```

If I run the code above -without adding anything to the manifest or the xml file- it will display the message "camera available!", so that part seems to be working fine.

However, when I add the file_paths.xml file my application crashes while building. I get the message:

> invalid resource directory name: obj\Debug\res file_paths.xml "res file_paths.xml".   demoApp_Xamarin.Android C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Skola\demoAppar\Xamarin\demoApp_Xamarin\demoApp_Xamarin\demoApp_Xamarin.Android\aapt.exe

It seems as though the file path to the file file_paths.xml is incomplete. As if a backslash is missing. (I don't know how to fix it, though. Or even if that is the actual problem.)

I also get the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The second message appears whenever I create a file called file_paths.xml, no matter where I put it.

Comment: I also have had the same problem with my application. Try changing the `Build Action` property of the `file_paths.xml` from `Content` to `AndroidResource`. This works for me in a test app but not in my current project.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan thank you for the suggestion. Sadly, it was already set to AndroidResource by default.

Comment: Have you tried using the plugin in a new blank application? My app crashed as I was running it, only when the `Build Action` is set to `AndroidResource`. > Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f07001a occurred. This exception occurs even if I remove my Firebase code.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan yes. I tried it first in a new app. It was crashing and got my annoyed, so I deleted it and created a new one (second application) but I got the same results. I figured maybe I had messed something up the first time, but apparently not.

Not sure if this is worth mentioning; I created both my projects as ".NET standard".

Answer (score 0):

**In Android:**

1>**inside manifest**:

a)**Add permission first** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

b) Create provider inside application tag :

```
<application android:label="Application Name" android:icon="@drawable/appIcon" android:largeHeap="true"> <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="applicationPackageName.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true"> <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/> </provider> </application>
```

c)create xml folder inside Resource directory:
inside xml :: 
create file_paths.xml:->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" /> <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" /></paths>
```

2>Inside ViewModel :

```
  public ICommand _capturePhoto;
    public ICommand CapturePhoto
    {
        get
        {
            return _capturePhoto ?? new Command(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!CapturePhoto.CanExecute(null)) return;

                    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        SaveToAlbum = true,
                        CompressionQuality = 75,
                        CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                        MaxWidthHeight = 2000
                    });

                    if (file == null)
                        return;
                    var fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(file.Path);
                    AddAttachmentToCollection(file.Path, DocumentType.Photo,fileExtension);
                    file.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but in your android manifest I think you are missing an @ for the file_path file, because you are "linking" to a resource file.

It should be

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@file_paths"></meta-data>
```

I have my file_paths file in a folder called "xml" and my code is

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
           android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
```

and that is working.

Comment: I have tried changing the android:resource="" path to everything I can imagine. I've used forward-slashes, backslashes, with @, without @. Typing out the complete path (Resources/xml/file_paths.xml), typing only the filename. I feel like I've tried everything, but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: I didn't read that you also created a folder called xml. So it should be @xml/file_paths